# spamassassin - set custom nameservers, rather than relying on resolv.conf?

Tags: spamassassin

Someone suggested to me that you can now set a custom nameserver for SpamAssassin to use when doing RBL/BL checks. Currently I get this error:

```
0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was
                             blocked.  See
                             http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
                              for more information.
                             [URIs: mcusercontent.com]
  0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_BLOCKED  RBL: ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to
                             DNSWL was blocked.  See
                             http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
                              for more information.
                             [205.201.133.30 listed in list.dnswl.org]
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on this though. How do you go about setting it up? I'm using SA 3.4.2

On my old server I would just edit resolv.conf and turn off the server "auto-update networking" options on my Linode. It seems that isn't possible any more on later systems, so I'm trying to find a work-around

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/CachingNameserver

```
SpamAssassin local.cf

dns_available yes

/etc/resolv.conf

search example.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1

NOTE: If something like NetworkManager is reverting your changes in /etc/resolv.conf or you don't have permission to update the /etc/resolv.conf, you may specify a DNS server in the local.cf:

dns_server 127.0.0.1
```

So what I did:

1. I already had "unbound" installed (apt-get install unbound)
2. Updated the SA **local.cf** file to include:

   ```
   dns_server 127.0.0.1
   ```

This now forces SA to use my custom nameservers (compared to the resolv.conf ones, which are global DNS and as such go way over the free usage limits in seconds)